# Text manipulation in ant

Tags: ant

Given an ant fileset, I need to perform some sed-like manipulations on it, condense it to a multi-line string (with effectively one line per file), and output the result to a text file.

What ant task am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a conbination of tasks:

This strips the '\r' and '\n' characters of a file and load it to a propertie:

```
<loadfile srcfile="${src.file}" property="${src.file.contents}">
  <filterchain>
    <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.StripLineBreaks"/>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

After loading the files concatenate them to another one:

```
<concat destfile="final.txt">
  ...
</concat>
```

Inside **concat** use a **propertyset** to reference the files content:

```
<propertyset id="properties-starting-with-bar">
  <propertyref prefix="src.file"/>
</propertyset>
```

Comment: That's very good ... I don't think you got all the details of the question down, but that shows me enough to make a full ant solution, if I want.

I'm not manipulating the contents of files.  I have a list of files built with a <fileset> tag; I want to apply an Ant <mapper> to the list (basically to strip off some directories and other transformations) and spit the whole thing out to a file, one per line.

Comment: So given what you shared with me, I could echo the <fileset> to a file, load it back in with a <filterset>, and then write back out to a file.  That'd be pure ant.  I hate making the roundtrip to an extra temp file, though.

Comment: Yes, it simply is that bad to have an extra file. :)  It's something I might choose to live with, but it's very messy!  I learned the lesson of not leaving extra files lying around at every step 10 years ago in the UNIX shell, and I'd like to avoid it in ant.

Answer (score 5):

The Ant [script](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) task allows you to implement a task in a scripting language.  If you have JDK 1.6 installed, Ant can execute JavaScript without needing any additional dependent libraries.  The JavaScript code can read a fileset, transform the file names, and write them to a file.

```
  <fileset id="jars" dir="${lib.dir}">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>

  <target name="init">
    <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
        var out = new java.io.PrintWriter(new java.io.FileWriter('jars.txt'));

        var iJar = project.getReference('jars').iterator();
        while (iJar.hasNext()) {
            var jar = new String(iJar.next());
            out.println(jar);
        }

        out.close();
    ]]></script>
  </target>
```

Comment: Jim, that is awesome!  Didn't see that before I started subclassing ant tasks.  I had seen something similar for Groovy, but didn't want to incorporate Groovy into our project just for this.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [ReplaceRegExp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) optional task.

> ReplaceRegExp is a directory based task for replacing the occurrence of a given regular expression with a substitution pattern in a selected file or set of files.

There are a few examples near the bottom of the page to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

rodrigoap's answer is enough to build a pure ant solution, but it's not clean enough for me and would be some very complicated ant code, so I used a different method: I subclassed ant's **echo** task to make an **echofileset** task, which takes a **fileset** and a **mapper**.  Subclassing **echo** buys me the ability to output to a file.  A **regexmapper** performs the transformation on filenames that I need.  I hardcoded it to print out each file on a separate line, but if I needed more flexibility I could add an optional separator attribute.  I also thought about providing the ability to output to a property, too, but it turned out I didn't need it since I echo'ed straight to a file.